# MimeBodyPart getContent corrupts binary data

Tags: java, mime, jakarta-mail, mime-mail

I use javax.mail.internet.MimeBody* version 1.4.1

My program wants to send some binary data with multiple level of nesting from a server to client using MimeMultiPart. I observed that if on a level if we use GetContent it corrupts the data. I was able to reproduce this problem with this snippet

```
  public static void CreateResponse() throws Exception {
        //Simulate the Server side
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        MimeMultipart multiPartValues = new MimeMultipart();
        MimeBodyPart valueBody = new MimeBodyPart();

        byte[] firstKeyValue = new byte[] { (byte)0x8c};
        valueBody.setContent(firstKeyValue,"application/octet-stream");
        valueBody.addHeader(RestMessageHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH,
                Integer.toString(firstKeyValue.length));
        multiPartValues.addBodyPart(valueBody);

        Object input = valueBody.getContent();
        System.out.println(String.format("input %02X", ((byte[])input)[0]));
        multiPartValues.writeTo(outputStream);

        //Simulate the client side
        byte[] mimeOutput = outputStream.toByteArray();

        ByteArrayDataSource ds = new ByteArrayDataSource(mimeOutput,
                "multipart/mixed");
        MimeMultipart mp = new MimeMultipart(ds);
        MimeBodyPart part = (MimeBodyPart) mp.getBodyPart(0);

        byte[] myOutput = new byte[1];
        //Verified that getContent returns a String, why ?? 
        Object output = part.getContent();
        System.out.println("getContent type " + output.getClass());
        String result = (String)output;
        ByteArrayDataSource partDS = new ByteArrayDataSource(result, "multipart/mixed");
        partDS.getInputStream().read(myOutput); 
        System.out.println(String.format("getContent %02X %02X", result.getBytes()[0],result.getBytes()[1]));
        System.out.println(String.format("getContent %02X", myOutput[0]));

        part.getInputStream().read(myOutput);
        System.out.println(String.format("getInputStream %02X", myOutput[0]));

        part.getRawInputStream().read(myOutput);
        System.out.println(String.format("getRawInputStream %02X", myOutput[0]));

}
```

Here is the output

```
        input 8C
        getContent type class java.lang.String
        getContent C2 8C
        getContent C2
        getInputStream 8C
        getRawInputStream 8C
```

I have completely simplified the code here and it looks obvious to use get(Raw)InputStream, but we have nestedMultiPart and the top level was doing getContent which caused it to fail for some cases.

1. Input is of type byte Array, but on the client getContent responds with String. The server sets the content to application/octet-stream but on the client side it is outputted as string. What is going wrong here?
2. I am not sure why the byte c2 is added before 8c. What is so special about the 8c character?
3. What is the difference between getInputStream and getRawInputStream. When to use one over the another ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does the complete stream contain that the server is creating and the client is reading?

Note that by using MimeMultipart without MimeMessage, you're missing some of the things that are done automatically for you by MimeMessage, in particular you're missing the call to MimeMultipart.updateHeaders().  Since the method is protected, you'll need to subclass MimeMultipart and call that method before calling writeTo.  If that doesn't fix your problem, show us the exact data that's being written and read on the stream.

As mentioned above, if you're expecting binary data, you almost certainly want to use getInputStream.  The getRawInputStream gives you the data before it has been decoded, e.g., the base64 input instead of binary output.

Comment: We have a key value server ( Project Voldemort) and we use MimeMultiPart to transmit the message from the server to client. The Key and Value are byte arrays. We are using MimeMultiPart to handle the serialization/deserialization.  Does using MimeMessage fix it ? Also not still sure about the last line. You meant to getInputStream for base64 and getRawInputStream for the byteArray ?

Comment: This may be longer than I can explain in a comment...  There are parts of JavaMail that are "lazy".  MimeMessage hides some of that from you.  If you're not using MimeMessage, you have to deal with those aspects yourself.  Read the javadocs for the updateHeaders method and let me know if you don't understand.

Comment: The getInputStream method returns the decoded data.  It has nothing to do with byte arrays.  The getRawInputStream returns the encoded data.  It has nothing to do with byte arrays.  The setContent method might accept a byte array, but the getContent method will return an object appropriate for the MIME type.  If the MIME type isn't handled specially (as the text types are, for example), getContent will just return an InputStream and you have to process the bytes however you want.

Comment: Thanks Bill. I have one final question, if you want to send some byte arrays, then the answer I suppose is use 
1) wrap everything in a MimeMessage , as MimeMultiPart may not serialize/deserialize correctly
2) use getInputStream instead of getRawInputStream ( both of them should be the same for byte arrays in theory).

Comment: There's still some confusion there.  If you can use MimeMessage, that will make it easier.  If you can't, you need to create your own MimeMultipart subclass so that, before you call the writeTo method, you call the updateHeaders method.  Once you do that, MimeMultipart will serialize correctly.  Once the data is serialized, any knowledge of whether or not it came from a byte array is lost.  On deserialization, it's just a stream of bytes, which you can read into a byte array if that's what you want.

Comment: Thanks @Bill Shannon that really helps. One final question do you see any issue with sending raw byte arrays versus base 64 encoded byte arrays. Currently we have a MimeBodyPart which sends raw byte arrays and it is working fine for all byte ranges ( not sure about consecutive byte combinations though)

Comment: JavaMail will choose an appropriate encoding for you, you shouldn't need to worry about it.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for your response. Will do my experiments with mime message and update here

Answer (score 0):

Don't use getContent() if it returns a String and you want binary. String is not a container for binary data. Use getInputStream() and copy the bytes.

Comment: I wish it was simple as you say. Get content  returns object. Before serialization it was byte array but after de serialization it returns string.

Comment: I do not understand this comment. What's not simple about using getInputStream()?

Comment: GetContent returns an object. Before Serialization the object was byte array. But after serialization/ de-serialization the Object was String. So GetContent is not always faulty. Also not sure about the difference between GetInputStream and GetRawInputStream.