# How can I send mail with byte array which is compressed by GZIP and rename it with **.csv.gz?

Tags: java, csv, jakarta-mail, gzipoutputstream

I am trying to send mail with byte array which is compressed by GZIP, and then rename it with **.csv.gz. I can not open the **.csv file, however, and it shows the file is broken.

I sent it by the following code:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream obj = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
gzipOS = new GZIPOutputStream(obj);
gzipOS.write(content.getBytes());//content is csv format
byte[] data = obj.toByteArray();
return data;
```

---

I tried many mime types, but it does not work:

```
DataSource dataSource2 = new ByteArrayDataSource(data, "text/plain");  
messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(dataSource2));
messageBodyPart.setFileName("kk.csv.gz");
```

This attachment is sent successfully, but when I open it with 7-zip, and try to compress it, it shows this file is *broken*.

Is there any way to slove this problem?

I think this is caused by the formatting when I rename it with **.csv.gz
but **.csv.gz is necessary.

Tips: disk is not allowed to save the file, so I send it by this way.

Comment: The fact that you're using text/plain with UTF8 for binary data strikes me as suspicious. There is an answer here that I believe may be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23023583/mimebodypart-getcontent-corrupts-binary-data

Comment: I had tried many mime types, it does not work.

Comment: You definitely want to use the right MIME type, e.g., application/octet-stream.  Also, be sure to close gzipOS when you're done writing.

Comment: After gzipOS.write(...), try calling .finish(). I haven't tried this, but I thought that there might be some data that had not been flushed to the stream. Doing some searching online mentioned a .finish() method.

Comment: When calling gzip.close not need to call gzip.finish   because finish is not closing the stream  and write the string, close write and close.

Comment: Thanks for your kindness , I had finished this issue, that is because I forget to close the stream, I original close the stream by finally{} , so this byte array will return partly before closing it, this make the data miss.